# What are the implications of AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) being put into maintenance mode in 2023?

Tags: aws-sdk, deprecated, aws-sdk-js

We are using Lambda service to run our JavaScript codebase. We have noticed the following message:

```
ERROR (node:8) NOTE: The AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) will be put into maintenance mode in 2023
```

1. Is there any info as to which month is AWS aiming the maintenance for?
2. Will Lambdas suddenly stop working with the SDK v2?
3. Will we be able to still deploy new Lambda versions if we include version 2 via Lambda layer?
4. I also assume that any new features/functionality that is added to AWS services is not going to be extended for AWS v2?

Sorry for this many questions. My main concern is when is this happening and what is the impact on existing deployments and codebases.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/maint-policy.html#version-life-cycle